# ActiveRecord query through multiple relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to make query where i get all class A which are in relations with class D, with particular name (class D has name column). But there are also class B and C between and actually i don't know how can i handle this with joins and merges.

The relationships are as below:

```
class Appointment
 has_many :booked_classes
 has_many :classes, through: :booked_classes
end

class BookedClass
 belongs_to :Appointment
 belongs_to :Class
end

class Class
 belongs_to :Teacher
 has_many: BookedClasses
end

class Teacher
 has_many :Appointmentss, through :Clasesses
 has_many :Classes
end
```

Comment: user `includes` method

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Appointment.joins(classes: [:teacher]).where(teachers: { name: "your_name" }) #"your_name" is the name to be matched with the value in name column of Ds table
```

Comment: Ok, i'm really bad at activerecord:) As a result i get: `#<#<Class:#<A::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe487623068>>:0x3ff243b11834>` I'm not sure if i use proper pluralisation. And should i use name of clases or symbols?

Comment: `A`, `C` & `D` are placeholder for Model class name. You can try it in your `rails console` using `to_sql` method to verify what SQL is getting generated.

Comment: `SELECT "a's".* FROM "a's" INNER JOIN "b's" ON "b's"."a_id" = "a's"."id" INNER JOIN "c's" ON "c's"."id" = "b's"."c_id" AND "c's"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "d's" ON "d's"."id" = "c's"."d_id" WHERE "D"."name" = 'test'`  
But i just get this strange object instead of collection of As

Comment: and when i'get `.first` i have error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'C' was not found on A; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Shouldn't there be some join with B also?

Comment: @user2576342 Do you really have model class name as `A` , `B`, `C` and `D` ? These names are pretty confusing and no meaning of using them. As per rails convention when you have model class names as `Category` `Product` then association should be like **Category** `has_many :products` i.e a plural form of model name `Product`. Similarly, **Product** `belongs_to :category` i.e a singular form of model name `Category` while establishing a one-to-one association. Your naming convention is not as per Rails standard.

Comment: nope:) but it is more universal like that i thought: A is Appointment, B is BookedClass , C is Class, and D is Teacher

Comment: `Class` is reserved class in Ruby, I think you should avoid using that.

Comment: still the same, i got result as in first comment, not the collection of Appointments

Comment: @user2576342 can you try the updated answer and post the result of `to_sql` on the active record query ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [includes method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

**Example:**

```
Article.includes(:category, :comments)
```